# Parsing text contents to java objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have text file looking like this:

```
CREATE EntityGroup ORG_KPKALX_CFM
  EntityChild ORG_UNIT.ORGKALX
  EntityParent  ORG_UNIT.OU_ORG_UNIT
  SCHEMA OU
  (IDNO = IDNO,
   IDTYPE = IDTYPE);

CREATE EntityGroup ORG_KPKAMR_CFM38
  EntityParent  ORG_UNIT.OU_ORG_UNIT
  EntityChild ORG_UNIT.ORGKAMR
  SCHEMA OU
  (CIFNO = CFRCIF);

CREATE EntityGroup ORG_WDPYMT_DDM
  EntityChild ORG_UNIT.ORGPYMT
  EntityParent  ORG_UNIT.OU_ORG_UNIT
  SCHEMA OU
  (BANKNO = DMBNO,
   ACTYPE = WDMBTY);
```

Above example has 3 entityGroup. In general it can have upto 100 such entities in a file. Entity Group is relationship between parent and child table.
But relationship can have multiple columns. column on left hand side of "=" is parent table column and column on right hand side of "=" symbol is child table column.
I need to map it to a object  and I have created class as below -

```
package com.test.common;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Realationship {

    String parentTable;
    String childTable;
    String creator;
    //parentcol=ChildCOL
    ArrayList<RelationshipColumns> cols;
    String EntityGroup;
    public String getParentTable() {
        return parentTable;
    }
    public void setParentTable(String parentTable) {
        this.parentTable = parentTable;
    }
    public String getChildTable() {
        return childTable;
    }
    public void setChildTable(String childTable) {
        this.childTable = childTable;
    }
    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }
    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }
    public ArrayList<RelationshipColumns> getCols() {
        return cols;
    }
    public void setCols(ArrayList<RelationshipColumns> cols) {
        this.cols = cols;
    }
    public String getEntityGroup() {
        return EntityGroup;
    }
    public void setEntityGroup(String EntityGroup) {
        this.EntityGroup = EntityGroup;
    }
    
}



package com.test.common;

public class RelationshipColumns {

    String parentColumn;
    String childColumn;
}
```

I am on java version 8. Can you please help me how can I add all relationships into the class object? Here there can be single or multiple relationship columns. Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

The following code only handles the sample data in your question.

- I assume that the `CREATE EntityGroup` line does not contain any leading spaces.
- I assume that the `EntityChild` and `EntityParent` lines have exactly two leading spaces.
- I assume that each *parent-child* line contains a single equals sign.
- I assume that parent and child column names contain only uppercase alphabetic characters.
- Hopefully, all my other assumptions will be clear from the below code.

Notes after the code.

Class `Relationship`

```java
package com.test.common;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Relationship { // Fixed typo in class name: Realationship
    private static final Pattern COLUMN = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+");

    private String parentTable;
    private String childTable;
    private String creator;
    private List<RelationshipColumns> cols; // Always code to the interface.
    private String entityGroup;

    public Relationship() {
        cols = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getParentTable() {
        return parentTable;
    }

    public void setParentTable(String parentTable) {
        this.parentTable = parentTable;
    }

    public String getChildTable() {
        return childTable;
    }

    public void setChildTable(String childTable) {
        this.childTable = childTable;
    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public List<RelationshipColumns> getCols() {
        return cols;
    }

    public void setCols(ArrayList<RelationshipColumns> cols) {
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    public String getEntityGroup() {
        return entityGroup;
    }

    public void setEntityGroup(String entityGroup) {
        this.entityGroup = entityGroup;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s|%s|%s|%s|%s", entityGroup, parentTable, childTable, creator, cols);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Relationship> relationships = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("entities.txt");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            Relationship relationship = null;
            line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("CREATE EntityGroup ")) {
                    relationship = new Relationship();
                    relationship.setEntityGroup(line.substring(19));
                }
                else if (line.startsWith("  EntityChild ")) {
                    relationship.setChildTable(line.substring(14));
                }
                else if (line.startsWith("  EntityParent  ")) {
                    relationship.setParentTable(line.substring(16));
                }
                else if (line.startsWith("  SCHEMA ")) {
                    relationship.setCreator(line.substring(9));
                }
                else if (line.contains(" = ")) {
                    RelationshipColumns rc = new RelationshipColumns();
                    Matcher matcher = COLUMN.matcher(line);
                    matcher.find();
                    rc.setParentColumn(matcher.group());
                    matcher.find();
                    rc.setChildColumn(matcher.group());
                    relationship.getCols().add(rc);
                }
                if (line.endsWith(";")) {
                    relationships.add(relationship);
                    relationship = null;
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            relationships.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class `RelationshipColumns`

```java
package com.test.common;

public class RelationshipColumns {
    private String parentColumn;
    private String childColumn;

    public String getParentColumn() {
        return parentColumn;
    }

    public void setParentColumn(String parentColumn) {
        this.parentColumn = parentColumn;
    }

    public String getChildColumn() {
        return childColumn;
    }

    public void setChildColumn(String childColumn) {
        this.childColumn = childColumn;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s=%s", parentColumn, childColumn);
    }
}
```

- I added a `main` method to class `Relationship` for testing purposes only.
- I assume that you want to create a list of `Relationship` instances from the contents of the text file.
- The `toString()` methods in both classes are purely for debugging purposes.
- I created text file named *entities.txt* which contains the sample data from your question.

Running the above code prints the following:

```
ORG_KPKALX_CFM|ORG_UNIT.OU_ORG_UNIT|ORG_UNIT.ORGKALX|OU|[IDNO=IDNO, IDTYPE=IDTYPE]
ORG_KPKAMR_CFM38|ORG_UNIT.OU_ORG_UNIT|ORG_UNIT.ORGKAMR|OU|[CIFNO=CFRCIF]
ORG_WDPYMT_DDM|ORG_UNIT.OU_ORG_UNIT|ORG_UNIT.ORGPYMT|OU|[BANKNO=DMBNO, ACTYPE=WDMBTY]
```